# Render cherrypy's template with id/hash

Tags: javascript, python, cherrypy

How would I render a page and go to a specific id?

Right now I have a following function with this code:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@require
def page():
    tmpl = lookup.get_template('page.html')
    return tmpl.render()
```

However, now the `page.html` does have several subpages, which I can access through URL like `mydomain.com/page#someid`.

Is there a way to render a template to go directly to the id?

Comment: What's wrong with the with the `#id` on the URL?. Can you provide a little more of context on why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with `#id`, I just don't know how to do that, since I'm accessing the template, which is a `.html` file and I can't do something like `lookup.get_template('page.html#id')`. And I don't know how to put the `#id` in the `tmpl.render()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mixing the ideas, the `#` part of the URL is the client duty to focus in the specific element id. Nevertheless, I suppose that you want to do that to dynamically embed chunks of a particular part of the page trough javascript, I can think on two possibilities:

One, compose the full page template with the different ids from different sub-templates, this is easy if you are using a template module, like [mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/), and make a cherrypy handler to return the indivudual parts, this is of course supposing that you are in control of the content of the page and the ids are not dynamic (generated from a db or something) and the main site is a bunch of `includes`.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def page_part(section):
    tpl_name = 'page_%s.html' % section
    # validate that the template exists, then:
    tmpl = lookup.get_template(tpl_name)
    return tmpl.render()
```

Mako templates:

page.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="main">
          This is the main content of the site!
      </div>
      <h4>Sections</h4> 
      <div id="section_1">
       <%include file="page_section1.html" />
      </div>

      <div id="section_2">
       <%include file="page_section2.html" />
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

page_section1.html:

```
<p> Content of section 1</p>
```

page_section2.html:

```
<p> Content of section 2</p>
```

Or two, use jQuery selectors or something similar to request the page once and make the sub-selects in the returned html.

```
$.get('/page.html', 
      function(data){
          $('#this_page_id').html($('#sect_in_other_page', $(data)).html());
      });
```

Comment: I'm in fact using `mako`. Will look into this. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit in detail, how the first method using `mako` would work?
If I would load my `page.html`, how do I append the page id, e.g. `sectOne`?

Comment: @cherrun I hope the improvement on the answer clarifies the idea.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see, how this is going to work. When I run `tpl_name = 'page_%s.html.' %section` and then `return tpl.render()` I will surely only get that specific, e.g. `page_section1.html` file, but not the whole `page.html` file where it then jumps to `section1`. It will just render that one page, without all the rest.

Comment: Basically you cannot control how is the client goin to be focused to a particular element without using javascript or specify that in the URL. In js you could do `document.location = '#mi_elem_id'` and that will focus to the element.